# Writing to a XLSX template and then sending it as a response in a different function, always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

**What I'm trying to do**

Requests come into my server to download a file containing data. The downloading part is in the front-end and works. I grab the data on my backend and then I want to write it into an existing template and return the data.

This is the handler for the request.

```js
async handle(request: Request, response: Response) {

    try {

      const fileName = 'test.xlsx'
      const binary = objectsToTemplateWorkBook()

      response.setHeader(
        'Content-Disposition',
        'attachment; filename=' + fileName
      )

      response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats')
      response.end(binary, 'binary')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      response.send(error)
    }
  }
```

This is the function that is supposed to write the data into the template.

```js
export const objectsToTemplateWorkBook = (): 
Promise<any> => {
  var XlsxTemplate = require('xlsx-template')
  var dataBlob
  // Load an XLSX file into memory
  const blob = fs.readFile(
    path.join(__dirname, 'test_template.xlsx'),
    function (err, data) {
      console.log(__dirname)
      // Create a template
      var template = new XlsxTemplate(data)

      // Replacements take place on first sheet
      var sheetNumber = 1

      // Set up some placeholder values matching the placeholders in the template
      var values = {
        people: [
          { name: 'John Smith', age: 20 },
          { name: 'Bob Johnson', age: 22 },
        ],
      }

      // Perform substitution
      template.substitute(sheetNumber, values)

      // Get binary data
      dataBlob = template.generate()
      // ...
    }
  )
  return dataBlob
}
```

The function seems to write the data to the template because if I log the dataBlob inside the fs.Readfile method it shows me the file. However, the return dataBlob always returns undefined. I know this is due to the async nature, but I have no idea how to fix it quite honestly. So my question to you is: how can I get the dataBlob to my handler to send it as a response?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the return from a callback function like you're doing here, since they run asynchronously, their return will never be acessible because the external return will be executed before the inner code.

To solve this specific problem you can you the `fs.readFileSync` function, that executes synchronously and returns a value, that being the buffer you need to pass in your xlsxTemplate constructor. This way, the code turns into:

```
export const objectsToTemplateWorkBook = (): 
Promise<any> => {
  var XlsxTemplate = require('xlsx-template')
  var dataBlob
  // Load an XLSX file into memory


  const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test_template.xlsx'))

  console.log(__dirname)
    // Create a template
  var template = new XlsxTemplate(data)

    // Replacements take place on first sheet
  var sheetNumber = 1

    // Set up some placeholder values matching the placeholders in the template
  var values = {
    people: [
      { name: 'John Smith', age: 20 },
      { name: 'Bob Johnson', age: 22 },
      ],
    }

    // Perform substitution
    template.substitute(sheetNumber, values)

    // Get binary data
    dataBlob = template.generate()
    // ...
    
  
  return dataBlob
}
```

With this you get access to the file buffer returned from the synchronous read file and is able to perform the rest of your operations. Hope it helps :D